# Connecting to Azure DevOps project

Tags: azure-devops

I have created an Azure DevOps project with the name *partsunlimited* but its teams are not popping up in Visual Studio Code. I have done CTRL + SHIFT + P and when I started typing TEAMS it is not coming up. What I am looking for TEAMS: PULL REQUEST option in Visual Studio Code.

I can see it in Azure DevOps:
[image]

When I start typing TEAMS it is not showing up, saying Not found
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on the information provided it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. So it doesn't enable us to help you. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: An Azure DevOps team is not something you explicitly connect to in Visual Studio Code. You probably want to clone the repo that's connected to the Azure DevOps project. See [Get started with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/get-started/?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi Rick, Thank you for the response. I have already clone repo and repo names "partsunlimited" and it is associated with teams in azure dashboard. However After opening that repo in the VS studio and Typed CTRL+SHIT+P to look for TEAM option which is not visible. Please help and find below screenshot ,  Probably you can see that screenshot in my previous thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the [Azure Repo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) Extension for your Visual Studio Code. Go to Extensions (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>) and select the `Argutec Azure Repos` to install.
[image]

If you are using the TFVC, then please go to **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) to set the user settings for TFVC. You can find the TFVC location under **User Settings** -> **Extensions** -> **Azure Repos**.

The `TF.exe` is installed with Visual Studio.

For 2017:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{version}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

For 2019:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\{version}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

Then under `Tfvc: Location` you can paste the location of the executable.

[image]

After that, open a local folder (repository - git clone from the Azure repo), or directly navigate to `Source Control` tab and select `Clone Repository` to git clone from your Azure DevOps repository.

[image]

If you are not the first time to open a folder/repo from Visual Studio Code, then you may not see the `Clone Repository` button as shown in above screenshot. In this case, please go to `SOURCE CONTROL` context and select `Clone` to git clone from your Azure DevOps repository.

[image]

You can get the git clone URL from Azure DevOps, the URL should be something like this:

```
https://user:PAT-Token@dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_git/Maven
```

[image]

Open the repo from Visual Studio Code, after a few moments, you'll see a "`Team`" label in the lower left corner of Visual Studio Code:

[image]

At this time, you can go to **View** -> **Command Pallette** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), type **team : signin** and provide the token to connect to your Azure DevOps project.

[image]

You can use other `Team` commands once your Azure DevOps organization is connected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already installed Azure Repo Extension in my machine. Please refer below screenshot. And I have chosen Login with VS studio when I started creating the repo. 
 I am not able to attach the screenshot of Azure repo extension installed status for some reason. and on the other hand I was trying to do enabling the setting as u have suggested but coming up with following error
Error while turning on Settings Sync. Please check [logs](command:workbench.userDataSync.actions.showLog) for more details. I am not able to attach or paste screenshots for some reason.

Comment: Please note that, it's not `TEAMS`, it should be `TEAM`. Basically, when you enter the string there, it prompts the command there. If you cannot see the `TEAM`, that means the  Azure Repos extension is not installed correctly. Please try to uninstall it and then reinstall it again.

Comment: After installing Argutec Azure Repos installed it is working and showing Team but when I click on sign in or team pull request comming up with following error. Please help   ERROR"  :   Team: View Pull Requests, Resulted in an error ( command 'team.GetPullRequests/ not found )

Comment: @shyamkumar The problem is that you are not connected to your Azure DevOps organization. I have updated  the answer, please exactly follow the steps to connect to your Azure DevOps repository. If it works, please mark it as the answer. Any further issues please free free to let me know.

Comment: In my case it is not asking for token at all. and I am still receiving same error. Please help. I have uninstalled and installed VS studio but residue is showing and giving same error.

Comment: @shyamkumar Have you cloned the repository from your Azure DevOps? Can you see the `Team` label at the left bottom of VS code? Anyway, a video for your reference here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnDNdm1WCIo. If you see the `Team` label, then you can click on the `Team` label on the bottom of your VS Code Screen to enter the token to sign in.

Comment: I have gone through video, But for me team itself is not showing on bottom left and also when I click on team sign in giving same error as before.

Comment: Please clone repository first, `https://user:PAT@dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_git/{your repo}`, make sure you can see `Team`, otherwise you cannot use the `Team` commands.

Comment: It is working now after watching the video, Please ignore previous comment Thank you for the support.